# php----deflate and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

What does these code mean? It is from the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can someone explain the last line? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to know about the rewrite rule?

`^`  start the expressoin

`^.` any character

`/`   then slash

`{3}` means match previous item 3 times

`^.` means match any character

`*` means match zero or more of the preceeding expression

`$` end the expression

`QSA` appends the variables passed to the end 
`L` means last rule

So match any character and then a slash (three times) and then any characters after it...

So

```
/a/b/c/myfile.txt
```

would be rewriten to

```
/index.php?page=/a/b/c/myfile.txt
```

and (for example from a login form post)

```
/a/b/c/myfile.php?username=myname&password=mypassword
```

would be rewritten to

```
/index.php?page=/a/b/c/myfile.txt&username=myname&password=mypassword
```

Comment: No problem...   While Regular Expression can be somewhat frustrating... You can get a lot of basic informatoin just searching for it..  Checkout http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php   and  http://www.regular-expressions.info/     ..  From there you should have the knowledge to search and learn regex and mod_rewrite.. (i would suggested then hitting up apache.org for more info)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
   </IfModule>
```

means: The output sent to the client will be compressed.
See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 1):

> The mod_deflate module provides the DEFLATE output filter that allows output from your server to be compressed before being sent to the client over the network.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Basically it compresses data sent by apache to then be uncompressed by the browser, reducing the payload sent between server and browser

Answer (score 0):

TheSetOutputFilter DEFLATE compresses traffic sent from the webserver to decrease response time and make the website faster.

The Rewrite Rule uses a regular expression to match a specific pattern in your URL and modify it so that something else happens.

```
  RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L] //expect someone can explain
```

Here is a resource on URL Rewriting:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html